# What does it mean by extra = "merge" in R Programming?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to wrangle my data. What does it mean by extra = "merge" in this code ?

```
dat %>% separate(key, c("year", "variable_name"), sep = "_", extra = "merge")
```

Comment: From `?separate` help file: "only splits at most length(into) times"

Comment: :-) Thanks for your help @Phil